# Protractor- I need a config option which runs after all the capabilities and before cleanup

Tags: protractor

I want to create a report in protractor after all the browsers are closed.
So I require an option in config that will run after all the capabilities and but before cleaning the global variables.

P.S. I tried afterLaunch() but it runs after cleanup. and also onCleanUp() but it runs for every capability.

Comment: Maybe you could add in a jasmine junit report into Protractor. Try this out. https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/jasmine-junit-reports

Comment: Thanks c nishina, but i have a custom method written for reporting, I just need to call it once after all the capabilities.

Comment: If you won't use an NPM module (reporter). Try creating a function saved in a separate ".js" and call that function when needed.

Answer (score 0):

`onCleanup` will make sure your report occurs after the browser finishes running specs, but right before the browser is torn down. This is the last chance you will have access to any global variables changed during the test, because it is the last phase of protractor.

As you mentioned, this will generate a report for every browser instance, but the global variables are global only for that browser instance, so I think it's what you want.

If you want to aggregate the results from all of the browsers, you will have to write out each of the reports in the onCleanup, and then join them together in a shell script (or javascript file) that runs after protractor finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below method

```
 onComplete: () => {
        console.log('onComplete');
    },
```

onComplete - A callback function called once all tests are finished. If onComplete returns a promise (optional), Protractor will wait for the promise to resolve before shutting down webdriver. At the time onComplete runs, tests will be done but global objects will still be available.

to refer more http://timothymartin.azurewebsites.net/protractor-before-and-afters/

Comment: Will this be called once after all the capabilities?
Because in my knowledge it will run for every browser.

Comment: onComplete runs for every browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in `conf.js`. This will be executed once all suites have finished execution.

```
// Close the report after all tests finish
afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
  });
}
```